# Can I set the HttpMethodAttribute Name attribute dynamically for a ASP.NET Core WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm learning to build CRUD Web API with ASP.NET Core.

According to some tutorials provided by Microsoft, this is how the `GetById()` method and other methods referring to it work:

```c#
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetItem")]
public IActionResult GetById(long? id)
{
    // get result item here ...
    return new ObjectResult(item);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] T item)
{
    // add new item into context here ...
    return CreatedAtRoute(
        "GetItem",
        new { id = item.Id },
        item
    );
}
```

For the CRUD methods do quite similar things to me, now I'm trying to make it a generic CRUD controller.  However, I'm stuck with the `Name = "GetItem"` part.

I had 2 different controllers inheriting this CRUD controller, but they still shared the same route name, "GetItem", and it failed to be `Name = "{_routeName}"` or several different tryouts.

Is it possible to make this `Name` attribute dynamic?  Or maybe any other suggestions to build a generic CRUD controller?  Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this implementation. It's for web api 2 but should get you goind in the right way https://www.strathweb.com/2018/04/generic-and-dynamically-generated-controllers-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Comment: @MarcusHöglund Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for.